# jquery-mmenu: prevent close on click

Tags: jquery, mmenu

How can I prevent jquery-mmenu from closing itself on click of a menu element? I've tried intercepting the "closing" event, but the menu is already closed if I put a breakpoint in my handler... (and also even so "preventDefault()" doesn't seem to do anything).

Thanks!

Comment: If I handle the closed event and trigger open in it, this seems to work, but a less hackish solution would be preferable.

Comment: Can you add some code to give us context to your issue? Perhaps a fiddle showing your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the "onClick.close" option to "false" should do the trick:

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    onClick: {
        close: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Messing with code from 10 years ago when the docs are gone. You win the internet today @Fred!!!